# Displaying dropdown of links with query builder

Tags: c#, html, razor, umbraco, dropdown

I am trying to create a dropdown in Umbraco 7, using the query builder. The dropdown is part of a navbar, which contains links to other pages as well. The page contains HTML with Razor code.

```
@{
                            var selection = Model.Content.Site().FirstChild("Sprog").Children()
                                                .Where(x => x.IsVisible());
                        }
                        <ul class="sf-menu well" data-type="navbar">
                            @foreach(var item in selection){
                                if(item.Name == "Sommerhuse") {
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="@item.Url">Sommerhuse</a>
                                            @{
                                                var selection2 = Umbraco.TypedContent(1090).Children()
                                                                    .Where(x => x.IsVisible());
                                            }
                                            <ul>
                                                @foreach(var sommerhus in selection2){
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="@sommerhus.Url">@sommerhus.Name</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                }
                                            </ul>
                                    </li>
                                } else {
                                    <li>
                                    <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
                                </li>
                                }

                            }
                        </ul>
```

I tried nesting another query builder with the content I need for the dropdown into my navbar query builder and iterating through that

But this still doesn't create the dropdown. Instead it just returns a static link, where the dropdown should be shown. In my HTML prototype, the dropdown works fine using this code.

```
<nav class="nav pull-right">
                        <ul class="sf-menu well" data-type="navbar">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="index.html">Forside</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="index-1.html">Lejebetingelser</a>

                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="index-2.html">Sommerhuse</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="sommerhus.html">Blokhus</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Hvide Sande</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Langeland</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Marielyst</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Ebeltoft</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Rørvig</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Bogense</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="">
                                <a href="index-4.html">Kontakt</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```

Apologies for the bad formatting, for some reason Visual Studio refuses to auto-format .cshtml files.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `<nav class="nav pull-right">` in your razor script.

Tip: do not compare on the name of a page because this will break your dropdown if the content editor changes the node name.

```
if(item.Name == "Sommerhuse") { // BAD IDEA
```

rather use the documentTypeAlias (if it is another document type)

```
if(item.DocumentTypeAlias == "aliasOfTheDocumentType") { // much safer
```

That will only work if the page has a special document type of course.